# logstash with java10 get error : Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'

Tags: logstash

I'm running `logstash` with Java 10 as follows:

```sh
./logstash -f std_std.conf
```

but I get this error:

```sh
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Thank you so much in advance.

---

Sorry. I've found out **Java 10 is not supported**. Closing.

Answer (score 6):

As @kylekong said, `java 10` is not supported. You could install `java 8` instead. Using Ubuntu you should do something like this:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless -y
apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -y
java -version
wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list
apt-get install apt-transport-https
apt-get update && apt-get install logstash
exit
```

Then you can start `Logstash` with:

```
sudo systemctl start logstash
```

Reference: `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/installing-logstash.html`

Answer (score 5):

You probably have Java 10 (not proper version). 
You should install Java 8 (Ubuntu solution):

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

It won't automatically change your default java compiler. Your should make it by your own. Change default java compiler:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Type 0 or 1 or 2 ... option. Probably last entry.
Now:

```
./logstash -f ../your-logstash-file.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the install guide... it is supported.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html

"Elasticsearch requires Java 8 or later. Use the official Oracle distribution or an open-source distribution such as OpenJDK."

Answer (score 0):

In the [Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/installing-logstash.html) for installing Logstash, it was mentioned that Logstash requires Java 8.

> Logstash requires Java 8. Java 9 is not supported. Use the official Oracle distribution or an open-source distribution such as OpenJDK.

You can download [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and try again. Hope it helps.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

$ ./bin/logstash -f logstash.conf 
Sending Logstash's logs to ...
```