# I can't install CASSANDRA on macBook

Tags: java, macos, cassandra

I am trying to install cassandra, I have done the following steps

- download [JAVA](https://www.java.com/es/download/)
- download [CASSANDRA](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/cassandra/3.0.18/apache-cassandra-3.0.18-bin.tar.gz)

```
MacBook-Pro:bin rodo$ ./cassandra
MacBook-Pro:bin rodo$ [0.002s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:./../logs/gc.log instead.
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

[image]

[image]

download what CASSANDRA asks and at the moment of running it still appears to me

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#prerequisites

Comment: Look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623648/logstash-with-java10-get-error-unrecognized-vm-option-useparnewgc/51275818 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334649/does-cassandra-support-java-10

Answer (score 1):

The current latest released version of Cassandra (3.11.4) only supports Java 8. Java 8 supports the UseParNewGC JVM option.

You have installed Java version 10 or later, which doesn't support this JVM option.

You can find it in the pre-requisites of Cassandra (http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#prerequisites):

> **Prerequisites**
>
> The latest version of Java 8, either the Oracle Java Standard Edition 8 or OpenJDK 8. To verify that you have the correct version of java installed, type java -version.

You need to downgrade your Java, or you need to use the unreleased version 4 branch of Cassandra.

Comment: do you have a repositore? or link for the donwload